# Is Whyburn's theorem on irreducible maps optimal?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

Whyburn's theorem (1939) says that a continuous surjection $q:Y\to X$, with $Y$ and $X$ compact and metrisable topological spaces, is irreducible if and only if the set of singleton fibres is dense in $Y$. Here *irreducible* means that there is no proper closed subset of $Y$ that $q$ maps surjectively onto $X$. I am not sure if it is part of the original theorem, but one can show that the set of singleton fibres is a $G_{\delta}$ in $Y$.

My question is, can the map $q$ be irreducible and the set of non-singleton fibres be dense in $Y$? I presume that the answer is yes, but I can't think of an example.

Comment: Let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set and let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $C$ with $x\sim y$ iff $x,y$ are endpoints of the same interval that was removed during the construction. The quotient map $C\to C/\sim=[0,1]$ should be an example

Comment: Many thanks. I was starting to think that there should be an example along these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set and consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $C$ defined by $x\sim y$ iff there is an interval removed during the construction of the Cantor set whose endpoints are $x$ and $y$.

The quotient map $\pi\colon C\to C/\sim\cong[0,1]$ is an example of an irreducible map which has a dense set of non-singleton fibers.