# Singleton fibres of irreducible quotient maps from $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $q: [0,1]\to X$ be an irreducible quotient map (*irreducible* meaning that no proper closed subset of $[0,1]$ maps subjectively onto $X$) with $X$ Hausdorff. By Whyburn's theorem (1939) the set of singleton fibres is dense in $[0,1]$. Does the set of singleton fibres contain an open subset of $[0,1]$?

(The answer is no if $[0,1]$ is replaced by the Cantor space, as someone has kindly pointed out recently: [Is Whyburn's theorem on irreducible maps optimal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341720/is-whyburns-theorem-on-irreducible-maps-optimal))

Comment: I think this is probably true, but I don't have time to think about it right now!